# remove parameter and its value from querystring in php

Tags: php

i have the following redirect script.

i have a redirect script that uses a querystring param to know where do redirect to. would like to strip out the param and its value and rebuid the query-string before it redirects. so the referrer does not contain the param value.

this is my currently code.

```
  $check   = $_GET['param'];    
    function redirect($location) {
          header("Location: $location");
        exit;}

        if($_GET['param'] === '1'){
        redirect('http://domain.com/');
        }
```

Comment: that's not really going to help. referer is always the address of the page you're currently ON. if the url that lead to the above code has a query string, then that string willl (maybe) be present in the referer, no matter what you do with the url you're using for the `Location:`.

Comment: im trying to change the current page. not the destination page

Comment: then you need a double redirect. e.g. you're on `example.com?foo=bar&remove=me`, meaning you first need to redirect to `example.com?foo=bar`, THEN redirect to the outside site. that way the outside site only sees `foo=bar`, and the redirect=me has vanished.

Comment: yes. thats what i need. how do i do it ?

Answer (score 3):

Just unset it and then build it:

```
unset($_GET['param']);
$querystring = http_build_query($_GET);
```

Comment: Depends on where you use it.  You haven't shown the query string anywhere in your question.

Comment: querystring is.  lets say page.php?param=1

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15dbc60e72930d0700100869c91337f4c6a7262c

Answer (score 1):

> ... would like to strip out the param and its value and rebuid the query-string before it redirects. so the referrer does not contain the param value.

Use `parse_url()` for it.

Here's the reference:

- [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

So your code should be like this:

```
function redirect($location){
    // $location = "http://example.com?something=value";
    $components = parse_url($location);
    $url = $components['scheme'] . "://" . $components['host'];
    header("Location: $location");
    exit;
}

$check   = $_GET['param'];   

if($check === '1'){
    redirect('http://domain.com/');
}else{
    redirect($check);
}
```

Comment: the $location is the destination url. im not trying to edit the destination. only the querysting of the current page and then reload the page before redirecting

Comment: @SammyMiri It doesn't edit or change the URL, it just strips out the parameter and it's value from the URL, just as you said in your question. Did you test it?

Comment: i tested it. its not removing the param from the current page im on.

Comment: *im trying to change the current page. not the destination page*...not sure what exactly you're trying to do.